# Vue copy text to clipboard from dynamically created components

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In Vue I have a button that generates components with different information from an array.
Once the information is generated and displayed I need to implement a function that copies this information when clicking on a specific item.
So far I am able to output the inner html text for each element, however I'm struggling to have this information copied to clipboard when the users clicks it because the elements are generated dynamically.
I have already tried this in my method: `target.select(); document.execCommand("Copy");`
This is what I have so far:

Here I use a loop to iterate over an array where all of my html elements are stored.

```
<p class='margin-top-10 margin-bottom-15' v-for='(captionItem, key) in captionInfoData' :key='key' v-html="captionItem" @click="copyCaptionData"></p>
```

This is one of caption item resulted from the iteration:

```
<div class="caption-info">
   <p class="wrapper name-wrapper">
      <span class="caption-label margin-right-10">Name:</span>
      <span class="caption-data name">Sofa</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

This is my function that so far outputs the inner html of clicked element:

```
copyCaptionData(e) {
   if(e.target.matches('.caption-data')) {
      let target = $(e.target);
      console.log(target.text());
   }
}
```

How can I copy the targeted text to clipboard?

Comment: Try `target.select(); document.execCommand("Copy");`.

Comment: @ThRnk I should have mentioned in my post, I have already tried that without success.